# Reallocation intervals of <vector> library (c++)

Tags: c++

I'm trying to understand how to dynamically allocate more space in a dynamic array in the most efficient way.

So I tried to understand how the reallocations are made in the `std::vector` library. According to [this](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/):

> "Libraries can implement different strategies for growth to balance between memory usage and reallocations, but in any case, reallocations should only happen at logarithmically growing intervals of size so that the insertion of individual elements at the end of the vector can be provided with amortized constant time complexity"

What does "logarithmically growing intervals of size" mean?
Assume I now have an array with capacity n and there is no vacancy at all. What would be the next reallocation?

Also, how exactly does the amortized complexity become constant?
I'd really appreciate an explanation about how it is more efficient than reallocation's by constant, i.e, say now we have an array of length n with no vacancy, the reallocation would be an array of n+constant, say n+15.

Comment: `new_capacity = capacity * factor;`.

Comment: `capacity + constant` doesn't grow logarithmically.

Comment: Amortized complexity analysis is rather complex. I would recommend that you acquire a good book on the subject.

Comment: i remember an excellent article that contains a proof for the amortized constant complexity, unfortunately I dont find it anymore. This is another one that might help: https://www.ics.uci.edu/~thornton/ics46/Notes/AmortizedAnalysis/

Comment: @user17732522 That's what I thought

Comment: @DirichletIsaPartyPooper The site you are using is known to have some issues and be out-dated. https://cppreference.com is a much better reference to the language.

Answer (score 3):

The sentence is wrong. It is supposed to say

> at exponentially growing intervals

or practically speaking usually a geometric series is used to achieve this, since it only requires multiplying the capacity by a constant at each reallocation.

With the geometric series allocation points are at sizes `a^k` with positive integers `k` and constant factor `a>1`, the sum is asymptotic to `a^(k_max+1)/(a-1)` and given that `k_max` must be so that `a^k_max = n`, we have then a total complexity of at most `n*a/(a-1)`, averaging to constant amortized.

Comment: Or "geometrically growing", since we are dealing with a series of discreet values.

Comment: @ChristianHalaszovich I doesn't necessarily need to be the geometric sequence exactly. Any exponentially growing sequence would suffice, but I added a remark.